# Mac mini Late 2014 No power after HDD upgrade

Tags: startup, hardware, upgrade, mac-mini

I've followed a very reputable guide online on doing a HDD upgrade with the proper tools and setup. I feel as if every step was followed properly yet the Mac currently doesn't power on. Could someone give me any clues on how to begin trouble shooting the hardware. Any links to information would also be appreciated as I'm a beginner to Mac hardware.

Thank you.

Comment: Only thing I can suggest is take it apart again & double-check every connection.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the suggestion. Done that already and all connections are solid.

Comment: If you put the old HDD back in, does it work?